# How can I check if a DJI aircraft is ready for takeoff?

Tags: dji-sdk

I have an app running on IOS (Swift) using the DJI mobile SDK.  At the moment, I still need to use the dJI GO app to determine if the aircraft is ready for takeoff (not in a no fly zone, compass is calibrated, etc.).  Is there a way to see those issues from the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the iOS UXSDK this is already built in using [class DUXPreflightChecklistManager](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-uilib-api/Widgets/DUXPreflightChecklistManager.html?search=flightmana&i=0&#duxpreflightchecklistmanager_overallstate_inline)  and you can find sample code here: [Mobile-UXSDK-iOS >DULPreflightChecklistManager](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-UXSDK-iOS/blob/master/docs/API%20Reference/Widgets/DULPreflightChecklistManager.html). If you do not want to use the UX iOS SDK and want to build your app purely from the iOS SDK then you will need to find each api for the features included in a preflight and build your own logic to have them do a check and throw errors at the startup of the RC and aircraft.  For example: [class DJIBattery](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/Battery/DJIBattery.html), [flyZoneManager](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/SDKManager/DJISDKManager.html?search=flyzone&i=0&#djisdkmanager_flyzonemanager_inline) or [isFirmwareVersion:newerThanVersion](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/BaseClasses/DJIBaseProduct.html?search=firmware&i=3&#djibaseproduct_isfirmwareversionnewerthanversion_inline)